# php - facebook quick login

Tags: facebook, authentication

I am trying to price up a quote and one thing on there is a facebook 'quick' login on the members area of the site in question. I think it is like open id. Is there any tutorials that anyone know of to accomplish this?

Comment: **I am trying to price up a quote** what does it mean?

Comment: it's not really that important.

Answer (score 4):

I guess there should be a fair number of tutorials out there:

1. [How to Authenticate Users With Facebook Connect](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/how-to-authenticate-your-users-with-facebook-connect/)
2. The Facebook PHP-SDK has a nice [example](https://github.com/facebook/php-sdk/blob/master/examples/example.php) that could be used (with some work) to achieve what you want.
3. I've written a [tutorial](http://www.masteringapi.com/tutorials/how-to-use-facebook-registration-plugin-as-your-registration-system/15/) about the [Registration Plugin](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/registration) (one of the flows) if you are interested.

Comment: +1 I like the tutorial you've written. Much better than the facebook Registration Plugin documentation.

Comment: @karim79: Thanks a lot! Feel free to tweet/like it! ;-)   Hope everything is good in Bahrain mate

Comment: things in Bahrain are... horribly messed up. Apart from that though, facebook's documentation is horribly fragmented; I've been implementing their registration system on a site with it's own one. It took around four days to get anywhere, and your tutorial gave me confidence that I was doing it right, while providing some additional insight. You totally deserve being the #1 facebook tag answerer.

Answer (score 0):

There are many tutorial which will be helpful in Login with Facebook as well as you can login with multipal sites.
You can use [PHP OAuth API: Authorize and access APIs using OAuth](http://www.phpclasses.org/package/7700-PHP-Authorize-and-access-APIs-using-OAuth.html)

written by Manuel Lemos. It provides built-in support for OAuth servers of Bitbucket, Box.net, Disqus, Dropbox, Eventful, Facebook, Fitbit, Flickr, Foursquare, github, Google, Instagram, LinkedIn, Microsoft, RightSignature, Salesforce, Scoop.it, StockTwits, SurveyMonkey, Tumblr, Twitter, XING and Yahoo.

Also

1. http://www.9lessons.info/2011/02/login-with-facebook-and-twitter.html

   2.http://www.a2zwebhelp.com/login-with-facebook

   3.http://runnable.com/UfwdES1fQz9uAAAh/simple-facebook-connect-php-example